# Cannot call method in main method

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a method in another method (like in C#), like this:

```
public class Exercise1
{
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   public int FirstNumber;
   public int SecondNumber;
   public int Answer;

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       GetNumbers();
   }

   private void GetNumbers()
   {
       System.out.print("Type in the first number: ");
       FirstNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Type in the second number: ");
       SecondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       Answer = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

       System.out.print("The answer is: " + Answer);
   }
}
```

Why can't I call the method like that?

Comment: @AJJ We are all learning, what is unknown for some is basic for someone else. Who has the right to decide that his is the proper level to ask a question? Of course there will be books written to answer practically any question you might come up with... And if there weren't, I don't think that'd be the level StackOverflow has been made for...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access `non static` methods in a `static` context.

Since main method is static you cannot access non `static` methods inside it.

Possible solutions:

**Solution 1.**

Make your     `GetNumbers();` as `static`. Then you are able to access it.

```
  private static void GetNumbers()
   {
      }
```

But, I won't recommend in your case, because you are accessing other instnace mebers too in `GetNumbers()`  method. So they also needs to be `static`.

**Solution 2.**

Create **new** object for `Exercise1` class inside main method.

```
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       Exercise1 ex= new Exercise1();
       ex.GetNumbers();
   }

   private  void GetNumbers()
   {
       System.out.print("Type in the first number: ");
       FirstNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Type in the second number: ");
       SecondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       Answer = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

       System.out.print("The answer is: " + Answer);
   }
```

And as a side note:

Please follow [java naming conventions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58), variable names stats with small letter's.

```
   public int firstNumber;
   public int secondNumber;
   public int answer;
```

Answer (score 4):

`GetNumbers();` needs to be `static`. A static method can only call a `static method` or use `static fields`.

However, but it can access `object.GetNumber()` if the `object` instance of `Exercise1` is local to the `main()`. That is, create an instance object of `Exercise1` in `main()` method to access that `Exercise1` object's `GetNumber()` method.

Answer (score 2):

main is static method whereas `GetNumbers()` is not static 
either make `GetNumbers()` to static or create an object in main then call `GetNumbers()`

like this way

```
public class Exercise1
{
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   public int FirstNumber;
   public int SecondNumber;
   public int Answer;

   public static void main(String [] args)

   {
Exercise1 e=new Exercise1();
       e.GetNumbers();
   }

   private void GetNumbers()
   {
       System.out.print("Type in the first number: ");
       FirstNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Type in the second number: ");
       SecondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       Answer = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

       System.out.print("The answer is: " + Answer);
   }
}
```

or

```
    public class Exercise1
{
   static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static int FirstNumber;
   public static int SecondNumber;
   public static  int Answer;

   public static void main(String [] args)

   {
GetNumbers();
   }

   private static void GetNumbers()
   {
       System.out.print("Type in the first number: ");
       FirstNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Type in the second number: ");
       SecondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

       Answer = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

       System.out.print("The answer is: " + Answer);
   }
}
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ where exactly

Comment: ohh sorry,I didnt notice that.Thanks I will modify it

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ please have a look now